# celery 4.3, SoftTimeLimitExceeded in group of tasks

Tags: celery, python-3.6

How should I handle SoftTImeLimitException with group of celery tasks?

i have task

```
> @shared_task(bind=True, priority=2, autoretry_for=(EasySNMPError,),
> soft_time_limit=10, retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 3, 'countdown': 2},
>              acks_late=True) def discover_interface(self, interface_id: int) -> dict:
>     logger.info(f'start disco interface {interface_id}')
>     p = probes.DiscoverSNMP()
>     try:
>         with utils.Timer() as t1:
>             p.discover_interface(interface_id=interface_id)
>             logger.info(f'stop disco interface {interface_id}')
>     except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
>         p.stats['message'] = 'soft time limit exceeded'
>         return p.stats
```

when i run it i get soft time limit exception.

log from celery

```
[2021-02-24 16:30:20,298: WARNING/MainProcess] Soft time limit (10s) exceeded for pollers.tasks.discover_interface[6b166746-95c4-458c-bb63-318bdb588d00]
[2021-02-24 16:30:20,374: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-2' pid:19585 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2021-02-24 16:30:20,393: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kolekcjoner/miniconda3/envs/kolekcjoner/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1267, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

execution in python console

```
job = group([tasks.discover_interface.s(1870361)]).apply_async()
In[45]: job.join_native()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kolekcjoner/miniconda3/envs/kolekcjoner/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-45-9330abace970>", line 1, in <module>
    job.join_native()
  File "/home/kolekcjoner/miniconda3/envs/kolekcjoner/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 818, in join_native
    raise value
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

how should i change it to NOT have exception in job.join_native(), but message 'soft time limit exceeded'returned from task?